# Ubuntu 18.04 LTS does not shut down completely

Tags: 18.04

Hi I am trying to shut down my laptop and it will only turn off the laptop display but the fans and keyboard light are still running continuously. I've tried to update the grub file but it did not work for me.

Is there any solution for this please?

I am using ubuntu 18.04 and my laptop is lenovo s145-15-api

Comment: Hi! Does sudo poweroff work? If it does, as a workaround you could a button that executes that command in the launcher. It's not a solution though but I said I would suggest it since no one has answered yet :)

Comment: no that doesn't work even non shutdown command not working I also changed the gnome config